# Cross-validation when there are near-duplicates in the data

Tags: cross-validation, modeling, nonparametric, text-mining, overfitting

I use cross-validation, with random partitioning, to test the generalization power of a certain classifier (a short-sentences classifier).

The problem is, my dataset contains many almost-identical samples, such as "I do not accept your offer", "I can not accept your offer", etc. So, when I partition the dataset randomly, there are many samples in the train partition that are very similar to samples in the test partition, and I get exceptionally high performance, which is actually over-fitting.

Is there a better way to test the generalization power of my classifier?

Comment: Old question, but in case you're still interested: If your sample has been drawn randomly from your population of interest, then it's just how your population of interest is. In this case, if you try to tweak the data, you will bias your sample and jeopardize the generalizability of your model. If you still suspect there may be an overfitting issue, in your place I'd investigate if there's some other source of data leakage - but in any case, similar observations are not a source of data leakage or overfitting, on the contrary they provide useful information for generalization.

Comment: NB: I don't post my previous comment as an answer, because I find there is not enough information in your question to provide a comprehensive answer. You should mention how the data has been collected, why you seem uncomfortable with having a lot of similar observations -besides the issue of overfitting-, and more details about the data, the problem you're trying to solve ultimately, and your model.